# No objects of __all__ are defined in numpy.random subpackage, but no errors are thrown upon importing

Tags: python, numpy, python-import, python-c-api

Why all the functions listed in __all__ (of the init file) of numpy.random subpackage work even though they aren't defined there?
I can imagine that they are written in C, but still when I do

```
from numpy.random import *
```

why doesn't Python throw an error since neither they are defined there (in the init file) nor is there seemingly any mechanism in the file that does the required imports.

Comment: The `__init__.py` has a `from .mtrand import *` import.  `np.random.mtrand` is a compiled `.so` file.  The `ipython` tab completion for `np.random<tab>` looks the same as that for `np.random.mtrand<tab>`.

Comment: The answer is mostly C extensions and Cython importing from compiled files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the lengthy name of mtrand file was the reason it was getting eluded for days from my eyes.

Comment: @hpaulj btw these 'so' files are new to me, so I was left wondering what are all the file extensions accepted by Python. Can you kindly let me know?

Comment: and if random functions are defined in 'mtrand', what is the role of 'randomkit.h'?

Comment: Filetypes depend on the platform. There might be .pyd and .pxd files (e.g. on windows) as well as .so files on *nix. https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html

Comment: @Dschoni Thanks for the reply, but isn't this '.pxd' extension a Cython thing instead of Python?

Comment: Yes it is. A lot of numpy modules are C extensions and therefore use Cython as an interface to Python.

Comment: In `https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/random` there's a cython source, a *.pyx`.  Then compiled and linked it becomes a `.so` binary.

Comment: And instead of `.so`, on Windows it becomes `.pyd`. See more here: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html

Comment: @hpaulj would you mind writing your comment as an answer